# The status checking doesn't rerun when apps/github_actions reopened the pull request

Tags: github, automation, github-actions, pull-request, cicd

I wrote the github action which runs the python script to send patch method for reopen pull request. The pull request included status checking that run another github action with trigger rule on 'reopened'. The job which connected to the status checking only reruns only if I intentionaly reopen the pull request (via Github web page or API). But if I use secrets.GITHUB_ACTION to reopen the pull request the job does not rerun. Why is it happening like that ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEXw0.png)

I were expecting that the job is rerun with secrets.GITHUB_ACTION and status checking is passed.